# Economic interpretation of a CES production function

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, economic-growth, production-function, aggregate-production

I am following a paper where a production function of this type is used.

$$Y=\left [\beta K^{- \rho}+\alpha \eta \left (\frac{K}{L} \right )^{-c(1+\rho)}L^{- \rho}   \right ]^{-1/\rho}$$

It is a modified version of a CES where in addition there is the term $\alpha \eta \left (\frac{K}{L} \right )^{-c(1+\rho)}$ which multiply the $L$ factor.

***I was therefore wondering. What may be the economic justification interpretation for adding this factor?***

Comment: May be to nest the Cobb-Douglas (if $\beta=0$) or the allow for nonconstant returns to scale (if $c=0$ we have CRTS). The reason should actually be given in the paper...

Comment: Yep.. if c=0 it nest a standard CES. But from a merely economic point of view, what's the sense that the production depends not just on K and L but also on their ratio?

Comment: The meaning is unclear. But is the dependence wrt $K/L$ not spurious as we can rewrite this term $ \alpha \eta K^{-c(1+\rho)}L^{- \rho + c + c\rho } $ ?

Comment: Yes, of course, you can rewrite the term that way. Mathematically adding $K/L $to multiply $L$. This means that if K increase (holding L constant) Y increase more than if we increase L (keepening K constant), because in the second case the $K/L$ ratio decrease and hence the $MP$ of Capital is sistematically higher than that of labor. Therefore it's like imagine that the production process is biased toward capital, right?

Comment: The production function is still homothetic and has CRTS (I made a mistake earlier), and as there is no technological change occurring here, I would not say that it is biased.

Comment: Yes I made a mistake too. This is what exactly change in terms of $MP$ by adding the term (above with, below without..i.e. standard CES).
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gQCCgMFe7wLNJxiRshko8Ziw_1AL0g_e/view?usp=sharing
What do you think?

Comment: Ok, I added some more observations to make it more clear. By adding $\alpha \eta \left (\frac{K}{L} \right )^{-c(1+\rho)}$ it's like if while $MP_{L}$ decrease to 0 as Y tends to infinity, $MP_{K}$ remains always positive.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K-wW7lf9mJJTcgCk16fUVUhIv3uxpDei/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It is always good practice to properly cite the paper in the question.